# How to read that star notation?

Tags: notation, vectors, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, quantum-mechanics

[[Click here to see the image I'm talking about - "The star notation for bracket of two vectors"]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQgST.jpg)

I'm learning Quantum mechanics on my own. While reading, I've now come across the Dirac notations. In the image attached, it is describing about the inner product of two vectors,
called as "Bracket of ket a and ket b" ,
which can be symbolically said as "bracket of |a> and |b> "  ,
and in mathematical symbols is written as <a|b>

While learning further, it is describing a property of the inner products and it is written that -

<a|b>  :=  <b|a>*

I don't know how to read that star notation. Can you please tell me ?

Comment: The star represents the [complex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate). In mathematics it is usually denoted by the overbar, so $\langle a,b\rangle=\overline{\langle b,a\rangle}$.

Comment: @Conifold   Thank you very much ! 